# ¿Cómo alinear horizontalmente dos botones agrupados con btn-group en la resolución móvil?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Buen día, estoy trabajando con Bootstrap 3 y tengo dos botones "Anterior" y "Siguiente" agrupados de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9 text-right" >
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span>&nbsp;Anterior</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Siguiente&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En la resolución para móviles los botones se visualizan verticalmente, independientemente de la unidad de rejilla que utilice.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder dejar ambos botones alineados horizontalmente para dicha resolución?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**:
Para que ambos botones tomen el 50% del contenedor en la versión móvil, utilicé estas dos clases CSS, dejo un ejemplo.

```
    <style>
        .contenedor-botones {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .boton-adaptado {
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9 text-right">
            <div class="btn-group contenedor-botones" role="group">
                <button class="btn btn-default boton-adaptado" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span>&nbsp;Anterior</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default boton-adaptado" type="button">Siguiente&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**NOTA**: Por favor, si encuentran una manera más limpia para evitar el uso de clases extras corríjanme.
Gracias.

Comment: Si no me equiboco, tu pregunta debería ser: _¿Cómo alinear **verticalmente** 2 botones?_   no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código a mi me funciona, no se el porque te falla a ti, el `div` superior a ese ¿que medida de rejilla usa? Quizás es inferior al de los botones juntos y eso ocasiona que la solución de `bootstrap` sea colocar un elemento abajo y uno arriba.

**Acá te dejo el código como lo uso en mi aplicación y me funciona perfectamente:**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span>&nbsp;Anterior</button>
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Siguiente&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></button>
</div>
```

**NOTA:** 
Si esto no te da solución, por favor, coloca el código completo de tu web para probar completamente la funcionalidad.

**Actualización 1:**

Aca el código con `btn-group` probado y funcionando:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-9 col-xs-12 text-right" >
     <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span>&nbsp;Anterior</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Siguiente&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></button>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Actualización 2:**
Tu problema esta en que no estas definiendo el `grib` de móviles para ello indicas el `xs`

> `col-xs-1` al `col-xs-12`

Comment: Hola Pablo, primero gracias por contestar, sin agrupar los botones con btn-group si se alinean horizontalmente. Mi duda es si es posible agrupándolos.

Comment: De nada, preguntaste arriba si se podían agrupar para móviles. Y eso respondí. Modifica tu pregunta sino está bien clara. Yo utilizo los btn-group. Dame un chance y te digo.

Comment: @GabrielDivenuto actualizado

Comment: Pablo sabés que así lo tenía, pero sin especificarle col-xs-12. Se visualizan horizontalmente, es raro ya que no he cambiado nada.

Comment: Te agradezco Pablo.

Comment: @GabrielDivenuto de nada amigo, para eso estamos. Te falta calificar como soluciona la duda que tenias y también votar la respuesta como positiva :D así cierras la preguntas y mas nadie se tomara la molesta de escribir una respuesta cuando ya se te solvento tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `display: flex` en el contenedor de botones

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9 text-right">
        <div class="btn-group d-flex w-100" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-default w-100" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span>&nbsp;Anterior</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default w-100" type="button">Siguiente&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Samir. Tardé en contestar pero volví a utilizar este sitio ahora que empecé con la versión 4 de bootstrap.

Comment: de nada, aproveche y actualice el codigo