# ¿Cómo puedo posicionar 3 botones alineados de forma horizontal?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código html

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
      <button style="margin: 1em auto" type="submit " class="send-btn">Enviar</button>
      <button style="margin: 1em auto" type="submit" class="send-btn">Modificar</button>
      <button style="margin: 1em auto" type="submit" class="send-btn">Cancelar</button>
</div>
```

Los cuales utilizan las siguiente clase css:

```
.send-btn {
    background: #d61010;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.4s linear;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1
}
```

En la pagina, me salen alineados de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que estuvieran alineados de forma horizontal, debajo del selector de archivos y centrados ¿Alguien me ayuda?

Comment: echa un vistazo a esta pregunta igual te puede ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46980/c%C3%B3mo-alinear-horizontalmente-dos-botones-agrupados-con-btn-group-en-la-resoluci

Comment: Prueba en el contenedor <div> de los botones: > .contenedor{ display:flex; flex-direction: row; }

Comment: Por favor recuerda añadir todo el código de la imagen que estás mostrando, para crear un [mre] apropiado.

Comment: Si esas usando bootstrap es facil, dentro de tu col-md-4 haz un row y dentro divides cada boton en 4 columnas y listo, sin necesidad de css extra

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el módulo flex-box para hacer alineaciones horizontales.

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 flex-container">
      <button style="margin: 1em 0" type="submit " class="send-btn">Enviar</button>
      <button style="margin: 1em 0" type="submit" class="send-btn">Modificar</button>
      <button style="margin: 1em 0" type="submit" class="send-btn">Cancelar</button>
</div>
```

```css
.flex-container {
  // Por defecto tiene un flex-direction: row
  display: flex;
}
```

Con esta regla todos los elementos contenidos por `flex-container`(flex-items) se posicionarán de forma horizontal (se ubican en forma lineal en el main-axis).

Si quieres controlar las posiciones de los flex-items en el main-axis puedes utilizar la propiedad `justify-content`